# C# Database connection

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a homework about database connection via ms access.

I prepared my database and saved it as dbMert and put it to debug / bin

This is my CustomerDatabase class for connecting to database:

```
static class CustomerDatabase
{

    static string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbMert.mdb";
    static OleDbConnection connection = null;
    static OleDbCommand command = null;


    public static void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
            command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Customer";
        }
    }     

    public static DataTable executeSelect(string sql)
    {
        ConnectToDatabase();
        DataTable dt = null;
        dt = new DataTable();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        OpenConnection();
        OleDbDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(datareader);
        datareader.Close();
        CloseConnection();
        return dt;
    }

    public static void OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

}

Form: In constructor i try to connect to database

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CustomerDatabase.ConnectToDatabase();
}
```

and in form's load i try to take tuples to datagridview but nothing happens :S

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql1 = "select * from Customer";
    DataTable dt = CustomerDatabase.executeSelect(sql1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write simple code. I suggest you to use [OleDbDataAdaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), its Fill() method populate the `DataTable` easily.

You may use |DataDirectory| if you are using database (.mdb) located under Bin\Debug folder.

```
static string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                             Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dbMert.mdb";
```

Or

```
static string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                              Data Source=x:\full_path\dbMert.mdb";
```

Or

```
static string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                              Data Source=x:\full_path\dbMert.mdb";
```

---

```
static class Test
{
    static string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbMert.mdb";
    public static DataTable executeSelect(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql,connectionString);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Add following code in form_load handler,

```
 string sql1 = "select * from Customer";
 DataTable dt = Test.executeSelect(sql1);
 DataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=dbMert.mdb"; but i think i have to install oledb 4.0 because the actual problem error is when i try to debug "oledb 4.0 is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: @mertPRG - Change the provider and set full path of database file. See the edited post. set Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\full_path\mydatabase.mdb;

Comment: Enable 32-bit Applications i have to do this true :S

Comment: when i changed its location there is  a argument exception with this  connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of other things (such as not keeping a single connection open, using `using` statements etc) you're not connecting your newly-loaded `DataTable` to your `DataGridView` at all. Your `Form1_Load` method *just* loads the data into a `DataTable`, then effectively throws it away.

I suspect you want something like:

```
 dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

at the end of the method.

EDIT: Note that this is also a *really bad* idea in your `OpenConnection` code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

That basically says, "If something goes wrong, don't bother recording that fact or changing how the rest of the code works - just keep going as if nothing had happened."

Why are you catching the exception at all?

Comment: i added it but nothing changed.Datagridview still is empty :S

Comment: @mertPRG: Have you tried debugging into it and seeing whether the `DataTable` ends up with any rows? Have you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to true on the view?

Comment: microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine i take this error when i try to debug.

Comment: @mertPRG: Right - so that sounds like the problem. This is a good example of why catching all exceptions and ignoring them is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

When I move the DB-file to `bin/debug`, an error message states "4.0 is not installed".

However, when I move it to bin, the problem is solved.

My code:

```
      con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= ..\\dbMert.mdb";
      con.Open();


    recordları
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      ds.Tables.Add(dt);
      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();



      da = new  OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Customer", con);
      da.Fill(dt);

      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;






      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
              if(col.ToString() == "emailAdress")
              comboBox1.Items.Add(row[col]);
      }




      con.Close();
```